# are "seekp" & "seekg" interchangeable?

Tags: c++, position, binaryfiles, fstream

Well I just noticed that by changing the position -in microsoft visual studio- through "seekp" I implicitelly also change the read-position, when handling files.

I am wondering however if this is "portable" behaviour? Can I expect the position of reading & writing to be always the same? And consequently: will `tellp` & `tellg` always return the same value?

Comment: **Related:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187297/seekp-and-seekg-dont-work-with-fstream

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For *file positions* they are the same. In other words there is only **one** pointer maintained.

From `27.9.1.1p3`:

> A joint file position is maintained for both the input sequence and
>   the output sequence.

So, `seekg` and `seekp` are interchangeable for file streams. However, this is not true for other types of streams, as they may hold separate pointers for the put and get positions.

Answer (score 13):

**Update:** So from all the comments and everything, it seems that for fstream, seekp and seekg use the same pointer. But for stringstream and probably other non-file based streams, they are separate.

---

**Original Post:**

Doesn't work for me on linux with g++ 4.7.2. They seem to be independent:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::stringstream s("0123456789");
    std::cout << "put pointer: " << s.tellp() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "get pointer: " << s.tellg() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    s.seekp(2);
    std::cout << "put pointer: " << s.tellp() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "get pointer: " << s.tellg() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    s.seekg(4);
    std::cout << "put pointer: " << s.tellp() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "get pointer: " << s.tellg() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
put pointer: 0
get pointer: 0

put pointer: 2
get pointer: 0

put pointer: 2
get pointer: 4
```

---

Also the behaviour you describe sounds like it doesn't comply with the quotes [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/):

> Sets the position of the get pointer. The get pointer determines the
>   next location to be read in the source associated to the stream.

and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/):

> Sets the position of the put pointer. The put pointer determines the location in the
>   output sequence where the next output operation is going to take
>   place.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted this, please leave a comment as to why ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can guess why: while what you've shown in accurate for a stringstring, it's *not* for a file stream.

Comment: yeah, makes sense :) I didn't see that fstream tag initially

Comment: @JerryCoffin Might be my mistake there partly; at first I only specified in the tags that I used fstream, made a small update afterwards :|