# seekp and seekg don't work with fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a strange behaviour in my c++ program running on Debian x64 PC.

I cannot manage to first read file, then write another value and then read these values.
I've read a lot of info, including questions on stackoverflow, found out (also via experiments) that I need to change both seekp and seekg and I do so.
Everything works... until I read something from a stream. After a read operation if I seek on begining of the file and then call tellg(), tellp(), they both return '-1'.

Test code:

```
void testFstreamSeekp() {
    fstream in("file", ios::in | ios::out);

    cout << "g: " << in.tellg() << endl;
    cout << "p: " << in.tellp() << endl;

    in.seekp(0, ios_base::end);

    cout << "endp g: " << in.tellg() << endl;
    cout << "endp p: " << in.tellp() << endl;

    in.seekp(0, ios_base::end);
    in.seekg(0, ios_base::end);

    cout << "end g: " << in.tellg() << endl;
    cout << "end p: " << in.tellp() << endl;

    in.seekp(0, ios_base::beg);
    in.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);

    cout << "beg g: " << in.tellg() << endl;
    cout << "beg p: " << in.tellp() << endl;

        // Everything is fine until here (that is tellp() == 0, tellg() == 0)
    int a, b;
    in >> a >> b;
    cout << "a: " << a << endl << "b: " << b << endl;

        // tellg() == -1, tellp() == -1 ?????????!!!!!!!!!!
    cout << "read g: " << in.tellg() << endl;
    cout << "read p: " << in.tellp() << endl;

    in.seekp(0, ios_base::beg);
    in.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);

        // tellg() == -1, tellp() == -1 ?????????!!!!!!!!!!
    cout << "beg g: " << in.tellg() << endl;
    cout << "beg p: " << in.tellp() << endl;
}
```

Can somebody tell me what happens and what can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: `seekp()/seekg()` won't work if the stream is in error state. How does your file look like and have you checked that it is succesfully opened?

Comment: Jrok, why didn't you post it as an answer? You solved me problem, thank you. Fstream was in eof() state after reading data. I've cleared the stream (in.clear()) and now it works like charm.

Comment: **Related:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329261/are-seekp-seekg-interchangeable

Answer (score 5):

For `fstream` (`std::basic_filebuf`), the single file position is moved by both `seekp()` and `seekg()`

Keeping track of `put` and `get` positions independently not possible.

The class template `std::basic_filebuf` holds a single file position

> § 27.9.1.1
>
> 1. The class basic_filebuf associates both the input sequence and the
>      output sequence with a file.
> 2. The restrictions on reading and writing a sequence controlled by an
>      object of class basic_filebuf are the same as for reading and
>      writing with the Standard C library FILEs.
> 3. In particular:
>
>    - If the file is not open for reading the input sequence cannot be read.
>    - If the file is not open for writing the output sequence cannot be written.
>    - A joint file position is maintained for both the input sequence and the output sequence.

Comment: That's exactly what I ment by 'I need to change both seekp and seekg'.

Comment: Thanks anyway, POW, now I understand that I need to use only one function (either of them) to move both pointers.