# Why does seekp/seekg exist for std::fstream when they both move one single pointer?

Tags: c++, std

The following code will output the same locations:

```
std::fstream fp;
fp.open("somefilename", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::ate);
if (!fp.good()) exit(1);
fp.seekp(100, std::ios::beg);
std::cout << "p: " << fp.tellp() << "  g: " << fp.tellg() << "\n";
fp.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
std::cout << "p: " << fp.tellp() << "  g: " << fp.tellg() << "\n";
```

So, assuming the file exists and holds at least 100 bytes, the output will be

```
p: 100  g: 100
p: 0  g: 0
```

My question is why stick to having two pointers in the API when they in reality are the same?
I know that the inheritance will "bring down" the virtual methods but I think it is a bit confusing since it's easy to make the mistake and believe there are two separate pointers, one for reading (get) and one for writing (put) when it's not.

Is it because some operating systems and/or hardware devices supports two separate pointers?

Cheers for any feedback :-)

Comment: My guess is that, both basic_istream and basic_ostream are acting on the same data member in basic_ios (or ios_base). I am sympatethic with your surprise, it seems a violation of the Liskov principle as well. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream

Comment: @dratenik I don't think the link explain "why", it just says in an official manner that "it is"

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi plus it provides an example of a stream (stringstream) where put & get positions are independent.

Comment: @dratenik I am not saying the link has no merit, indeed it is making me curious to understand why stringstream behave differently

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi Probably a limitation of the underlying OS, I don't think any mainstream OS (and/or POSIX) maintains a separate read & write position for file descriptors.

Comment: in the comment of the "already answered question" there is this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187297/seekp-and-seekg-dont-work-with-fstream that sheds some light on it. It is saying that the restrictions are the same as the C standard library FILEs. So, it could have been a design choice to make refactoring of code using the C way easier

Comment: At a guess, part of this is because seeking before each read and write could get expensive.

Comment: Reopened. The claimed dupe didn't address the question **why**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::fstream` acts as both an input stream and an output stream. You can write this code:

```
void f(std::ofstream& out) {
    out.seekp(whatever);
}

void g(std::ifstream& out) {
    out.seekg(whatever);
}

void q(std::fstream& str) {
    f(str);
    g(str);
}
```

In order for this to work, `std::fstream` has to provide both `seekg` and `seekp`.

Both functions manipulate the same pointer because operating systems don't necessarily distinguish read locations and write locations. When a stream deals with resources that aren't files (e.g., strings), the implementation can handle different read and write locations without complicated gymnastics.

Comment: So the real reason is then related to inheritance.
fstream inherits from iostream which inherits both from istream and ostream, while ofstream only inherits from ostream and ifstream from istream.
So maybe they chose to design it this way for API convenience. We have iostream and fstream just needs to inherit it and specialize to fiddle with the same pointer.