# What is difference between input position and output position in streams?

Tags: c++, stream

Is there difference between input position and output position in `basic_iostream`?

If I put bytes to a stream and I want to read them, what do I should use to read from beginning, `seekg()` or `seekp()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [are "seekp" & "seekg" interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329261/are-seekp-seekg-interchangeable)

Comment: You may google "stream seekg seekp" to find answers. One I found for SO, I proposed as possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

`seekg` sets the input position indicator of the current associated streambuf object.

`seekp` sets the output position indicator of the current associated streambuf object.

Using `seekg`, you can set the indicator at your required position and read from there.

For example, `seekg(0)` will rewind to the beginning of the streambuf object and you can read from the beginning.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
 
int main()
{
    std::string str = "Read from Beginning";
    std::istringstream in(str);
    std::string word1, word2, word3;
 
    in >> word1;
    in.seekg(0); // rewind
    in >> word2;
    in.seekg(10); // forward
    in >> word3;
 
    std::cout << "word1 = " << word1 << '\n'
              << "word2 = " << word2 << '\n'
              << "word3 = " << word3 << '\n';
}
```

Output is:

```
word1 = Read
word2 = Read
word3 = Beginning
```

For more info, see the documentation of [seekg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) and [seekp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp).

Answer (score 0):

The question is why do we need two positions?
some objects play dual roles, you can read from and write to them in a interleaving way. see std::stringstream, it implements both istream and ostream
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "hallo";
fill the buffer and sets the output position at the end of hallo (tail), BUT input position (head) is still at 0. So something can read from it.
It is implementation of QUEUE.