# How can I read a document and write to it at the same time

Tags: c++

```
struct employee
{
    string empid;
    string lastn;
    string firstn;
    float hours;
    float payrate;
    float taxrate;
};

const int SIZE = 100;
int main()
{
    employee eCount[SIZE];
    string empF;
    int count, option1;
    fstream inFile;

    inFile.open("personnel1.dat", ios::in | ios::out);

    count = 0;

    cout << "Enter an Employee ID to Change Values (i.e Cv299): ";
    cin >> empF;
    cin.ignore();

    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        count += 1;

        inFile >> eCount[count].empid >> eCount[count].lastn >> eCount[count].firstn >> eCount[count].hours >> eCount[count].payrate >> eCount[count].taxrate;

        if (empF == eCount[count].empid)
        {
            do
            {
               cout << "1. Change Employee's ID (" << eCount[count].empid << ")\n";
               cout << "2. Change Employee's Last Name (" << eCount[count].lastn << ")\n";
               cout << "3. Change Employee's First Name (" << eCount[count].firstn << ")\n";
               cout << "4. Change Employee's Hours Worked (" << eCount[count].hours << ")\n";
               cout << "5. Change Employee's Pay Rate (" << eCount[count].payrate << ")\n";
               cout << "6. Change Employee's Tax Rate (" << eCount[count].taxrate << ")\n";
               cout << "7. Quit!\n\n";
               cout << "Enter 1 - 7: ";
               cin >> option1;
               cin.ignore();

               switch (option1)
               {
               case 1:
               {
                   cout << "What would you like to change the Employee ID to?: ";
                   getline(cin, eCount[count].empid);
                   break;
               }
               case 2:
               {
                   cout << "What would you like to change the Employee's Last Name to?: ";
                   getline(cin, eCount[count].lastn);
                   break;
               }
               case 3:
               {
                   cout << "What would you like to change the Employee's First Name to?: ";
                   getline(cin, eCount[count].firstn);
                   break;
               }
               case 4:
               {
                   cout << "What would you like to change the Employee's Hours Worked to?: ";
                   cin >> eCount[count].hours;
                   cin.ignore();
                   break;
               }
               case 5:
               {
                   cout << "What would you like to change the Employee's Pay Rate to?: ";
                   cin >> eCount[count].payrate;
                   cin.ignore();
                   break;
               }
               case 6:
               {
                   cout << "What would you like to change the Employee's Tax Rate to?: ";
                   cin >> eCount[count].taxrate;
                   cin.ignore();
                   break;
            }
              default:
                break;
            }
        } while (option1 != 7);
    }
}
inFile << eCount[count].empid << eCount[count].lastn << eCount[count].firstn << eCount[count].hours << eCount[count].payrate << eCount[count].taxrate;
inFile.close();
}
```

The program is supposed to read the file and also allow the user to write to it. After inputting a valid employee ID it pops up the menu allowing the user to enter what they want to change. After inputting those changes and closing the file, it doesn't update the file. It still shows the same values from before.

Comment: How is `eCount` defined? Maybe it does not have a 0-th element or has fewer elements than there are lines in the file. At which line does the code crash?

Comment: @DanielJunglas the eCount is a struct that holds 3 strings and 3 floats. I somewhat fixed it so that it shows the menu, but now it doesn't update the actual file.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and focus on the word **minimal**

Comment: @ThomasSablik I hope that is enough

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Your code should be compilable. We should be able to copy and paste your code to reproduce the problem. Also please remove everything that's not related to the question like the menu and all the cases.

Comment: @ThomasSablik done, if i delete the menu you wouldn't understand what's happening

Comment: Try to use write() method of 'inFile'. Also before read the file, store current position of the file by 'tellg()' method, and when you want to update the record, first change the file position to that point and then update the record.

Comment: @BehnamArazkhani how were you able to do it? I'm new to fstreams

Comment: Do something like this: In your code before inFile >> .... add  long cur_position = inFile.tellg();  and then before inFile << ....   add   inFile.seekg(cur_position, ios::beg);

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like,

This code copies Line by line from old file to a tempfile. When you find the line which you want to update, change it with your line and copy it to the tempfile. Then finally copy all data from tempfile to file and delete tempfile

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::ios;

class Employee
{
public:
    std::string  empname;
    std::string  empid;
};

int main()
{
std::fstream file("emp"),tempfile("tempemp");
Employee emp;
std::string id;

if(!file.is_open()||!tempfile.is_open())
{
    file.open("emp",ios::out);              //create a file 
    tempfile.open("tempemp",ios::out);      //create a file
    if(!file.is_open()||!tempfile.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"File Error";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        file.close();         
        tempfile.close();
        file.open("emp");        // open file for both read and write
        tempfile.open("emp");    // open file for both read and write
        if(!file.is_open()||!tempfile.is_open())
        {
        cout<<"File Error";
        exit(1);
        }
    }
}


for(int i=0;i<3;i++)                 // taking 3 employee name and id
{
    cout<<"Enter Name and id:"<<endl;
    cin>>emp.empname;
    cin>>emp.empid;
    file.write((char*)&emp,sizeof emp);
}

cout<<"Contents:"<<endl;           //printing contents
file.seekg(0,ios::beg);            //move get pointer to beginning
while(file.peek()!=EOF)
{
  file.read((char*)&emp,sizeof emp);
  cout<<emp.empname<<endl;
  cout<<emp.empid<<endl;
}

file.clear();                         //reset file 

cout<<"Enter Id to Modify:"<<endl;
cin>>id;                              // which id to modify

file.seekg(0,ios::beg);              //move get pointer to beg
tempfile.seekp(0,ios::beg);          //move get pointer to beg

while(file.peek()!=EOF)
{
    file.read((char*)&emp,sizeof emp);
    if(emp.empid==id)               //if emp id in file equal to id then
    {                               //save to tempfile the name and id of user entered
        cout<<"Enter New name and id:"<<endl;
        cin>>emp.empname;
        cin>>emp.empid;
        tempfile.write((char*)&emp,sizeof emp);
    }
    else                          // if not equal save the content in file to tempfile
    {
        tempfile.write((char*)&emp,sizeof emp);
    }
}

file.clear();                   //reset file

tempfile.seekg(0,ios::beg);     //move get pointer pos to beg
file.seekp(0,ios::beg);         //move put pointer pos to beg
while(tempfile.peek()!=EOF)
{
    tempfile.read((char*)&emp,sizeof emp);         //copy contents of tempfile to file
    file.write((char*)&emp,sizeof emp);
}

file.clear();                             //reset file
tempfile.close();                         //close file
remove("tempemp");                        //remove tempemp pointed by tempfile

cout<<"Modified Contents:"<<endl;         //print modified contents
file.seekg(0,ios::beg);                   //move get pointer pos to beg
while(file.peek()!=EOF)
{
  file.read((char*)&emp,sizeof emp);
  cout<<emp.empname<<endl;
  cout<<emp.empid<<endl;
}

file.close();                       //close file
return 0;
}
```

i am used name and id only for simplicity

```
                                         (OR)
```

you can use like this also,But this code did not use tempfile. it replaces the new content directly in the file.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::ios;

class Employee
{
public:
    std::string  empname;
    std::string  empid;
};

int main()
{
std::fstream file("emp");
Employee emp;
std::string id;
std::fstream::pos_type pos=0;     //for position

if(!file.is_open())
{
    file.open("emp",ios::out);

    if(!file.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"File Error";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        file.close();
        file.open("emp");
        if(!file.is_open())
        {
        cout<<"File Error";
        exit(1);
        }
    }
}


for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    cout<<"Enter Name and id:"<<endl;
    cin>>emp.empname;
    cin>>emp.empid;
    file.write((char*)&emp,sizeof emp);
}

cout<<"Contents:"<<endl;
file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
while(file.peek()!=EOF)
{
  file.read((char*)&emp,sizeof emp);
  cout<<emp.empname<<endl;
  cout<<emp.empid<<endl;
}

file.clear();

cout<<"Enter Id to Modify:"<<endl;
cin>>id;

file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
file.seekp(0,ios::beg);
pos=file.tellp();              //get init pos
while(file.peek()!=EOF)
{
    pos=file.tellp();          //update pos
    file.read((char*)&emp,sizeof emp);
    if(emp.empid==id)
    {
        cout<<"Enter New name and id:"<<endl;
        cin>>emp.empname;
        cin>>emp.empid;
        file.seekp(pos);            // change pos 
        file.write((char*)&emp,sizeof emp);        //save modified content
    } 
}

file.clear();

cout<<"Modified Contents:"<<endl;
file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
while(file.peek()!=EOF)
{
  file.read((char*)&emp,sizeof emp);
  cout<<emp.empname<<endl;
  cout<<emp.empid<<endl;
}

file.close();
return 0;
}
```

In file streams only tellg changes tellp but it not for other streams for more info see this
[are "seekp" & "seekg" interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329261/are-seekp-seekg-interchangeable/14329311#14329311)